# SQL: Create a flag for separate records in the same table with overlapping date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, boolean

I'm trying to figure out how to create a boolean field that would tell me when two records have overlapping date ranges.

IN the following example, every unique Location/Counterparty combo within a specified date range can EITHER have a contract, or a DeliveryPoint, not both. So id 1&2 should be flagged, but id's 3 and 4 are ok because they don't overlap, so the flag should read "False".

I started to do a self join, but after that, I couldn't wrap my head around the next step. Did I start correctly, or is the solution totally different?

```
id  Location    Counterparty    Contract    DeliveryPoint     StartDate   EndDate
1   New York    Wal Mart                     Philadelphia     3/1/2019    12/31/2020
2   New York    Wal Mart        123456                        5/1/2019    7/31/2019
3   Toronto     Target                       Boston           3/1/2019    5/31/2019
4   Toronto     Target          456789                        6/1/2019    12/31/2020
```

With the flag, I'd want it to look like

```
id  Location    Counterparty    Contract    DeliveryPoint     StartDate  EndDate      Overlap
1   New York    Wal Mart                    Philadelphia      3/1/2019  12/31/2020    TRUE
2   New York    Wal Mart         123456                       5/1/2019  7/31/2019     TRUE
3   Toronto     Target                      Boston            3/1/2019  5/31/2019     FALSE
4   Toronto     Target           456789                       6/1/2019  12/31/2020    FALSE
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work?

Comment: What significance do the `Contract` and `DeliveryPoint` have? Do they factor into the `StartDate`/`EndDate` comparison at all? If not, I would remove the middle paragraph of your question. It doesn't add to the original ask and only draws attention away from the important part of the question, namely, comparing StartDate and EndDate.

Comment: The combination of a location and counter party can either have a contract or a counterparty at the same time, not both.

Comment: @Larnu I dm started a self join, but then couldn’t forgive our what to do to get the rows to to look at each other... like how would id-1 see that there is a contract on Id-2?

Answer (score 0):

On your insert query, I think you could create a subquery that search other record with overlapping dates. Please attention the date fields test. See the example:

```
insert into table(location, Counterparty, Overlap)
select
    @location, 
    @Counterparty, 
    case when exists(select Id
               from table t
               where t.location = @location
               and t.Counterparty = @Counterparty 
               and @startDate <= t.EndDate 
               and @endDate >= t.StartDate
              ) then 1 else 0 end as Overlap
```